# Is it possible to use MetaSearch on checkboxes for strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, meta-search

I have an index page of `Users` that I want to filter with a search form using MetaSearch. However the values I want to search when I checkbox is clicked are stored as strings. For example, here's a form I want to apply MetaSearch to:

```
<% form_for(current_user.profile) do |f| %>
<table id="careerCriteria">
  <tr>
    <td class="normal"><%= current_user.profile.hometown %></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :hometown %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="normal"><%= current_user.profile.current_city %></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :current_city %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="normal"><%= current_user.profile.past_city %></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :past_city %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I don't want to use a search button. I want the filter(s) to be applied when the checkbox (or checkboxes) are clicked. I'm new to programming so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a little ajax & query to accomplish this.

Here's a good article to show you how to make the checkbox submit the form.

http://trevorturk.com/2010/08/24/easy-ajax-forms-with-rails-3-and-jquery/

What you'll want to do is create an action in the controller that handles your search.  Here's an example of a search action...

```
def search
    if params[:term].blank?
        raise "You must provide search criteria."
    end

    params[:term] = "%#{params[:term]}%"
    conditions    = " Description LIKE :term"

    @careers = Career.all(
        :conditions => [conditions, params],
        :offset     => params[:offset],
        :limit      => params[:limit]
    )

    respond_with @careers
end
```

You'll also need to setup a route for this search for this action.

```
resources :careers do
    get "search/:term/:offset/:limit.:format", :action => "search", :constraints => { :offset => /\d+/, :limit => /\d+/ }
end
```

Once you get the form submitting to this action you should be able to use jQuery to update the results.

Now keep in mind if you don't want to use Ajax & jQuery to load the results you can do so, you'll just take the remote action out of the form tag and it will refresh the whole page.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I search using multiple terms? I want to allow the chance to filter by numerous different terms. For example, hometown, current_city, past_city.

Comment: You would need to use scopes in your models.   Here's a link to give you an overview.  It also has the benefit of showing you how to do exactly what you are looking for: http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your help thus far. I put up another question with all of the things I put together piecemeal on this. Can you take a look and help me figure out how to connect it all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466123/form-filter-on-index-page-using-cross-model-scope

Comment: Sure I'll try and take a look at it tomorrow.  Remember to marks questions as answered to keep your approval rating up!